Sonata Admin redirect after edit. Problem with caching an access upon editing an object
I am trying to redirect user to a show page after editing an object.
After editing an object certain flag is set and edit action is blocked to all users (all objects can be modified only once) using SecurityHandlerInterface.
class CustomSecurityAdminHandler implements SecurityHandlerInterface
{
    ...

    public function isGranted(AdminInterface $admin, $attributes, ?object $object = null): bool
    {
        if (!$object || $object instanceof AdminInterface) {
            return $this->defaultSecurityHandler->isGranted($admin, $attributes, $object);
        }

        if ($object instanceof Object && $attributes === 'EDIT' && $object->wasAlreadyModified) {
                return false;
        }

        return $this->defaultSecurityHandler->isGranted($admin, $attributes, $object);
    }

    ...
}

Therefore theoretically sonata should handle it on its own. In CRUDController Sonata redirects user after successfully editing an object
#Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController

public function editAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        ...
        // On valid submitted form
        return $this->redirectTo($request, $existingObject);
        ...
    }

then it checks if I have access to an edit page and if not it should redirect me to a show page
#Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController

    protected function redirectTo(Request $request, object $object): RedirectResponse
    {
        ...

        foreach (['edit', 'show'] as $route) {
            if ($this->admin->hasRoute($route) && $this->admin->hasAccess($route, $object)) {
                $url = $this->admin->generateObjectUrl(
                    $route,
                    $object,
                    $this->getSelectedTab($request)
                );

                return new RedirectResponse($url);
            }
        }

        return $this->redirectToList();
    }

The problem is that Sonata is caching an access from security handlers.
So at the beginning when I POST my changes I have an access since no changes were made yet. But after persisting changes my security handler returns no access granted. Unfortunately Sonata is not checking that access again since its cached and redirects me to an edit page which I have no longer access to.
#Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin

    final public function isGranted($name, ?object $object = null): bool
    {

        ...

        $objectRef = null !== $object ? sprintf('/%s#%s', spl_object_hash($object), $this->id($object) ?? '') : '';
        $key = md5(json_encode($name, \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR).$objectRef);

        if (!\array_key_exists($key, $this->cacheIsGranted)) {
            $this->cacheIsGranted[$key] = $this->getSecurityHandler()->isGranted($this, $name, $object ?? $this);
        }

        return $this->cacheIsGranted[$key];
    }

Is there any other way to redirect to a show page after editing an object (except overriding whole editAction)?
Or is that something that potentially could be reported to sonata team to change in their codebase? Like not checking a cached access if an object has changed etc.
Using

PHP 8.3
Symfony 6.4
Sonata Admin 4.30.1

